# Internet Explorer won't cache static files

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, caching, http-headers

Got this response header (request for some static file, i.e. some *.css):

```html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/css
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Set-Cookie: merp_session=eec953c0214e1; path=/; expires=Thu, 21-Feb-2019 15:34:06 GMT; HttpOnly
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token, X-Merp-Session-Id, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Expires: Fri, 22 Feb 2019 13:34:06 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=86400, private
Date: Thu, 21 Feb 2019 13:34:06 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: Identity
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Connection: Keep-Alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Last-Modified: Wed, 06 Feb 2019 11:05:35 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
X-Catalyst: 5.90115
```

Any other browsers take static from local cache, but IE always requests all files from my server again an again.

What kind of response headers should I set to force IE local cache?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the F12 developer tools Network tab and check whether you have turned on [the "Always refresh from server" option](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255004(v%3dvs.85)).

This option is a toggle switch with on and off states. When on, Internet Explorer 11 downloads all page elements from the remote server, not from the browser cache.

[image]

Edit:

Besides, you could also check the ["Check for Newer Versions of Stored Pages" setting](https://support.pearson.com/getsupport/s/article/Internet-Explorer-Check-for-Newer-Versions-of-Stored-Pages).

Comment: Sorry, but the problem is not in my IE, but users of my service. I can't tell everyone to switch this toggle =) So I'm searching for a server-side solution.

Comment: If the issue is related to the server-side, thus, other browsers (such as chrome and Firefox) will also meet the same issue. So, I think the issue is related to the IE browser, you could try to test the site on another computer IE browser or reset the IE browser to verify it. Here is an article about [Understanding Conditional Requests and Refresh](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/07/08/understanding-conditional-requests-and-refresh/), you could check it.